# Group by values in map using java streams

Tags: java, hashmap, java-8, java-stream

I have map of student grades in a class, i want to get count by grade, it can be done by iterating the values and then increasing count in a map is there better way using Streams.

```
    Map<String, String> grades = new HashMap();
    grades.put("100", "A");
    grades.put("101", "B");
    grades.put("102", "A");
    grades.put("103", "C");
    grades.put("104", "D");
    grades.put("105", "B");
    grades.put("106", "B");
    grades.put("107", "C");
```

my Output map should have A=2, B=3, C=2, D=1

Comment: Unfortunately not. If course you could do it with streams, but you would also have to use a data structure to count the occurrences - a HashMap like you suggested. And streams also iterate over the values, meaning you gain nothing. For large ``HashMap``s you might have a benefit using ``parallelStream`` though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `Collectors.groupingBy` like this

```
Map<String,Long> groupByGrades=  grades.values().stream().
      collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),    
      Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: Java 11 example on the Oracle docs, https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html uses summingInt